# How to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, ruby

The wiki suggests using `$sudo pacman -S ruby1.9` but the package isn't there... I'd rather not compile it from source but I can if no one knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use [rvm](https://rvm.io) to manage Ruby versioning.

First install rvm:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled
. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
```

You'll probably want to source that on shell startup as well, so add it to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'
[[ -r ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && . ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
EOF
```

Now install Ruby 1.9.3:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

If you want to set 1.9.3 as the system default, do this:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Comment: Oh yeah I just found the same thing haha

Comment: This is definitely the way to mange ruby installs, don't use the pre-built binaries that come with the system for anything other than management of the system itself.

Comment: works for 1.9.3 but fails for 2.1.0 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114969/installing-ruby-2-1-on-arch-via-rvm

Answer (score 2):

To manage different `ruby` versions installed simultaneously you have a choice of three ruby version managers:

- rvm, as suggested by [Chris Down in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75598/6761)
- [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/)
- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)

After trying all three on Arch, I would recommend `chruby`: it is simpler than the other two, is not as invasive in terms of how it works with your $PATH or overwrites `cd`, and does not require any executable shims.

It also isn't as "full-featured" as the other two, in that you will need to install [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to install additional rubies.

Overall, though, I prefer the lightweight, minimal-impact approach. There is a `chruby` package in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chruby/) and another for [ruby-build](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ruby-build/).