# I recently ran updates now the terminal doesn't see installed packages

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

I recently ran the system updater. At the time there was 400 updates. I installed them all and everything was peachy.

A few days later it showed that I had more updates. So, wanting to avoid getting to 400 updates again, I ran them. There was only 4 and they were all related to python libs.

These were all level 3 updates and I installed them the day after they came out (6/25/13).

I am a Ruby On Rails developer and the next day I came in and was working on a project, I went to run my rails server with the command `rails s` and I got this message:

```
rails is not currently installed please run apt-get install rails to install.
```

I then tried to run `rake`, `cap -f deploy`(capistrano), and even `ruby -v` and I got the same message for all of them.

RubyMine (my IDE) still sees that ruby on rails is installed, and I can run my dev server though that.This is not ideal however so:
**How do I make my terminal see my ruby on rails installation again?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Arch?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75596/how-to-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-arch)

Comment: @jasonwryan this is def not a duplicate. I don't have rvm installed and I don't need to manage multiple versions of ruby. For some reason my terminal isn't pointing to the correct version but my IDE is. I am trying to figure out how to get my terminal to point to the right version. Not download a version manager. I don't even want the old version and I don't know where it came from...

Comment: "Getting your terminal to point at the right version" sounds *a lot* like needing a version manager to me...

Comment: @jasonwryan read the rest of what I wrote. I don't want a version control manager because I don't want multiple versions! I want the one version that's been working for the last year till now. But when I uninstall the bad version that was installed when I ran the `apt-get install cap` command, it doesn't revert to using the correct version of ruby, it just says that **no version of ruby is installed at all!** There is a reason the question is long. Context matters. As far as my terminal is concerned the version of ruby I need and **know is installed** doesn't exist on the computer...

Comment: I can read. I also have some experience with ruby and managing various versions. ALL of the symptoms you describe point to versioning issues; the recommended way to deal with that is a version manager. In any event, you don't seem to want my help, so I'll leave you to it...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you for leaving. The actual question has nothing to do with versions. But because of your misunderstanding I have updated the question.