# Installing ruby 2.1 on Arch via RVM

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, ruby

I have problems installing ruby 2.1.0 via RVM on Arch. My vagrant provisioning file looks like this:

```
sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S vim --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S git --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S wget --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S gcc --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S clang --noconfirm
sudo pacman -S libyaml --noconfirm
```

rvm installs 'fine' and I'm able to install ruby 1.9.3 via it. However it fails for 2.0.0 or 2.1.0:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-archlinux ~]$ rvm install 2.1.0
ruby-2.1.0 - #removing src.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: arch/libc-2.19/x86_64/ruby-2.1.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for arch.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.0 - #downloading ruby-2.1.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.1.0 - #extracting ruby-2.1.0 to /home/vagrant/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0.
ruby-2.1.0 - #applying patch /home/vagrant/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.1.0/changeset_r44327.diff.
ruby-2.1.0 - #applying patch /home/vagrant/.rvm/patches/ruby/libyaml015.patch.
ruby-2.1.0 - #applying patch /home/vagrant/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-2.1.0 - #configuring....................................................
ruby-2.1.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.1.0 - #compiling..................|
..
Error running '__rvm_make -j1',
showing last 15 lines of /home/vagrant/.rvm/log/1392246637_ruby-2.1.0/make.log
transdb.h unchanged
making trans
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vagrant/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0'
compiling ./enc/trans/transdb.c
linking transcoder transdb.so
compiling ./enc/trans/big5.c
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
enc.mk:760: recipe for target 'enc/trans/big5.o' failed
make[1]: *** [enc/trans/big5.o] Error 4
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vagrant/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.0'
uncommon.mk:560: recipe for target 'trans' failed
make: *** [trans] Error 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you're running out of memory? Anything interesting on syslog or dmesg?

Answer (score 2):

Roberto Rodriguez Alcala is correct, you are running out of memory.

I've had exactly this problem, with Arch on my Raspberry. (B model with 512MB)

Creating a swap file solved the problem for me alternatively you can create a standalone swap partition if you like.

To create a swap file, (source Arch Wiki);

```
fallocate -l 256M /swapfile
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

To add a swap partition add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2 none swap defaults 0 0
```

Remember to use appropriate device where you created your swap partition, instead of `sda2`.

Answer (score -1):

**Install Ruby with RVM**

first run a update to make sure that all of package uptodate

```
# pacman -Sy
```

start installing RVM, Ruby Version Manager

```
# pacman -S curl
```

To install RVM

```
# curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After installing open .bashrc file

```
# vi .bashrc
```

Add this to the end

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This will start RVM on startup, exit your session and log backin.

RVM has some of its own dependencies that need to be installed

```
# rvm requirements
```

Before installing Ruby, you need to install libyaml if you plan on installing Rails

```
# sudo pacman -S libyaml
```

installing Ruby with RVM is easy

```
# rvm install 1.9.3
```

Ruby is now installed. However, since we accessed it through a program that has a variety of Ruby versions, we need to tell the system to use 1.9.3 by default.

```
# rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

If you need to install gems, follow this too
Install RubyGems

```
# rvm rubygems current
```

Install Rails

```
# gem install rails
```

check version Using

```
ruby -v
rails -v
```

If you lazy to work around above try this

```
# \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Or

```
# rvm list

# rvm use { your wish version }

# rvm use version which you installed
```

Comment: *Never* run `pacman -Sy; pacman -S $package`: [it will lead to breakage](http://gist.io/5660494)... Also, this doesn't answer the question: OP has RVM installed and ruby-1.9.3.